# Conditional sentence in the song "What Makes You Beautiful"

Tags: conditionals, lyrics, songs

A small part of the lyrics in the song "What Makes You Beautiful" is

> If only you saw what I can see, you'll understand why I want you so desperately.

But according to the second conditional sentence structure (If + Past Simple, Would + infinitive), should this sentence not be as follows?

> If only you saw what I can see, you *would* understand why I want you so desperately.

Comment: Song lyrics always have some leeway to fit rhyme and meter. If ungrammaticality bugs you, you should probably listen to instrumental :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about "grammatically correct" usage in the context of song lyrics, which often break syntactic rules for various reasons

Comment: @FumbleFingers Still perfectly reasonable to ask if a particular line *is* grammatical though, no?

Comment: Probably belongs on ELL because no native speaker talks about second conditionals.

Comment: Obviously there was no metrical requirement to say "you'll" instead of "you'd"—so I think we can set this choice down to the lyricist's personal preference for "you'll." Maybe that's the normal way to express constructions of this type in What Makes You Beautiful Land.